# How do I get the 'clear' command in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, ncurses

I installed Cygwin, choosing a fairly minimal set of packages.

In a terminal, I tried to do 'clear' to clear the terminal, but I get

```
bash: clear: command not found
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: You can also type control-L.

Comment: Yes, but (for me) that does not work in `set -o vi` mode; it _does_ work in `set -o emacs` mode though.  Thanks.

Comment: In `set -o vi` mode, you can type escape followed by control-L (then `i` to get back to insert mode). (Personally, I like vi as an editor, but not as an interactive shell mode.)

Comment: press ctrl+L to clear

Comment: Note that the `ncurses` package (as stated in the accepted answer) also includes other useful terminal-related commands such as `tput`, so it may be worth installing depending on your needs.

Comment: When I hit ctrl+L it does not clear the terminal, it just scrolls my current line to the top. The terminal appears clear but if I scroll up using the side bar I can see it is not clear at all. This  is very irritatint when debugging programs and wanting to clear the past data between compilations etc. Would like to be able to actually clear the terminal as I can in Linux

Comment: @MarnixKlooster not that it's optimal but even in vi mode you can exit input mode to normal via <C-Esc> or similar.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Install the Cygwin package `ncurses`; it is in the Utils category.

Comment: This package does not appear to be in the current cygwin 64-bit version.

Comment: @AndrewProck It seems to be there now!

Comment: Thanks for this! If you've already installed cygwin you can install ncurses by following the "Install ncurses" section here: http://java.ociweb.com/mark/programming/tmuxInCygwin.html

Comment: If you don't find ncourses, change mirror at the beginning of installation, or use the search box

Comment: My SpyHunter sees "clear.exe" as malware, and therefore blocks it, when I attempt to run it.

Answer (score 127):

This should do:

```
alias clear='printf "\033c"'
```

Comment: Great answer. In older versions of Cygwin, `cmd /c cls` used to work as described at http://stackoverflow.com/q/15598245/1207769. But that solution stopped working, whereas this `printf` still works as of this writing.

Comment: Excellent - still works as of sept 2014. Just for added clarity  note you can add this to your ./bashrc file (just copy and past the line) which you will find under /home/[username] and you will make this permanent.

Comment: This also works a charm for [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) bash, but msysgit has its own clear program in the bin directory

Comment: This is the best answer to clear scrollback as well as the current screen. Ncurses does not clear scrollback for me.

Comment: Great answer... You can use this even on production servers where you're not allowed to install packages (i know... Cygwin on production Windows servers.. not my choice xd). You just have to add it to your `~/.bashrc` file and `source` it and it's done... Nice job pointing that out

Answer (score 37):

just use this shortcut: `Alt+F8` and `Ctrl-L` to skip page

Comment: This is not what the user asked for, sometimes clearing a the screen is really useful for quickly making sure the output you get is from where you think it is from.

Comment: But not an answer at all to the question, if you put every slightly related piece of useful information on every stack overflow post then it would be monstrous.

Comment: A Google search for "cygwin clear screen" got me here, this answer was correct for me. You can be however strict you want about answers, scope, limits and whatnot - but as far as I'm concerned, this solved it for me and gets an up vote as truly "helpful".

Comment: And so the battle raged: the purists and the anti-purists shelling from opposite sides of the philosophical divide.  If a combatant was killed, he was tossed into the chasm, and as he fell both sides covered their ears to avoid hearing the screams of the Paradoxes.

Answer (score 15):

Use `cygcheck` command to check what package it is in (adding `.exe` to your cmd string, in this example: `clear.exe`)

```
> cygcheck -p 'clear.exe'
Found 4 matches for clear.exe
ncurses-debuginfo-5.9-20150307-1 - ncurses-debuginfo: Debug info for ncurses (installed binaries and support files)
ncurses-debuginfo-5.9-20150404-1 - ncurses-debuginfo: Debug info for ncurses (installed binaries and support files)
ncurses-5.9-20150307-1 - ncurses: Terminal display utilities (installed binaries and support files)
ncurses-5.9-20150404-1 - ncurses: Terminal display utilities (installed binaries and support files)
```

and you know you have to install `ncurses` package using cygwin installer.

Answer (score 13):

It's nice to have the `clear.exe` program for bash script files, so:

Windows Cygwin detail for `clear.exe` program command.

1. Download Cygwin `setupx86.exe` or whatever it's call at http://cygwin.com/
2. Run it and download from internet.  *If you have a proxy connection, you may need to use Internet Explorer settings or set up custom proxy.
3. Choose all default settings, and finish the installation.
4. Run the installer a second time and again download from internet, but this time you will go into `Utils`, when it comes to the tree of files to customize your installation.
5. Expand `Utils` and get down to the `ncurses`" files.  There, you will click on the `skip` item, to the left of the ncurses utils (there are a few).
6. After changing from `skip` to whatever version of `ncurses` you want to install, continue the installation, and finish.
7. Run the installer again and this time you will expand `Lib` aka libraries.
8. Find the terminfo library installer, and again change `skip` to the newest version, then continue and complete the installation.

**NOTE**  You might end up having to log out of Windows and log back in, or just reboot before the new programs take effect.  This is due to the possibility of Cygwin background session.

**NOTE** You also must do the three separate installations.

Comment: @Chris: I am asking this just for the sake of clarity. Why is terminfo database library required here ? The clear command worked fine for me. I read about terminfo (as provided [link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-16.html)) but want to know is there anything specific it does here ?

Answer (score 12):

I tried in my system: It works:

```
Just use: cntrl+l
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 11):

Right click > Reset... (Alt + F8) worked for me... (on Cygwin-x86-2.830)

Comment: +1 `Ctrl`+`L` and the ncurses `clear` command keep scrollback, whereas this clears it.

Answer (score 7):

Open Windows Explorer then navigate to:

> [Cygwin Installation Directory]\home\[User]\

`e.g.:  C:\cygwin\home\wreckseal`

then open the file `.bashrc` with Notepad++.

Move your cursor at the end of the last line and hit `Enter` key, then add the text below.

> alias cls='echo -e "\033c"'

or the text below:

> alias cls='printf "\033c"'

Restart cygwin, type `cls`.  Done!

Note that there's no scrollbar after sending the cls command. I prefer the `printf` version than the `echo` version. Try it yourself!

Answer (score 7):

## Search for "/clear.exe$" => Install "ncurses"

**TLDR:** Package search uses regular expressions. So searching for regex "/clear.exe$" will give you the best match. This leads to the `ncurses` package.

---

General approach to such problems:
Search on the [Cygwin-package search page](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi) with the full executable name.

Now the package search can be done in several ways:

- *Basic search by executable basename.*
  Package search for `clear`:
  https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=clear
  ->  Found **600** matches for **clear**
- *Better matches by including the `.exe` suffix.*
  Package search for `clear.exe`:
  https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=clear.exe
  ->  Found **14** matches for **clear.exe**
- *And even better matches by also including the `/` prefix.*
  Package search for `/clear.exe`:
  https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=/clear.exe
  ->  Found **5** matches for **/clear.exe**
- *Best matches by also including the `$` suffix.*
  (The `$`-sign means end-of-line in this regular expression.)
  Package search for `/clear.exe$`:
  https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=/clear.exe$
  ->  Found **3** matches for **/clear.exe$**

And all of these 3 matches are now from several versions of the `ncurses` package. So in order to get `clear.exe` you need to install `ncurses`.

*(Pro tip: Right-click the search-field and create a customized search engine. I have set this to the shortcut `cp` for "cygwin package" in both Firefox and Chrome.)*

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this project and so far, I think it's awesome

https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg

after installing it, you can run

```
apt-cyg install ncurses
```

I personally prefer installing libraries using this tool over the Cygwin tool b/c the Cygwin versions all have .exe appended to them, and can be cumbersome when copying and pasting Linux commands (off of SO, for instance).