# cygwin clearscreen from bash

Tags: bash, cygwin

I want to clearscreen from bash in a cygwin terminal.
I have tried

```
cmd /c cls
echo -e "^V^L"
echo -e "\014"
```

None of these work - they all give a "linefeed". Pressing CTRL+L does work - but I want to call it from a Bash script.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Mat: This has the same effect as Ctrl+L, it only pushes the text up off the screen but doesn't clear it

Comment: tput mentioned below should be part of ncurses.

Comment: The Control-L character (which is formfeed, not linefeed) typically doesn't do anything when printed on vt100-like terminal emulators.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11249070/1207769

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear the Ubuntu bash screen for real](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367068/clear-the-ubuntu-bash-screen-for-real)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If it's contained in your cygwin install (run Cygwin's setup and make sure you have the package called "ncurses"), try

```
tput clear
```

Comment: The real answer here is: install ncurses, then the "normal" clear command does work as Keith said.

Answer (score 171):

Or you could  try ctrl-L :)

That should work in most emulated terminals as well.

Comment: From the question: "Pressing CTRL+L does work - but I want to call it from a Bash script."

Comment: `CTRL+L` seems to only scroll away the old content, not remove it like `ALT+F`

Comment: Wow this answer sure is paying the bills! Sheesh, I wonder what "sudo !!" would get me.

Answer (score 67):

There is two ways:

**Using shortcuts**

`Alt+F8` to clear screen and `Ctrl-L` to skip page

**Using `Clear` alias**

1. Go to: `cygwin\home\USER\.bashrc`
2. Open `.bashrc` file and put this alias `alias clear='printf "\033c"'`.
3. restart your cygwin terminal.
4. to clear your screen use `clear` command.

Comment: From the question: "Pressing CTRL+L does work - but I want to call it from a Bash script."

Answer (score 26):

I have this in my ~/.bashrc:

```
alias clear='printf "\033c"'
```

likewise, printf "\033c" clears the screen from within a bash script.

Comment: Clever solution. Just added it to my .bashrc

Answer (score 2):

Alt+F8 to clear screen and Ctrl-L to skip page

Answer (score 1):

Using shortcuts (for `mitty` console users)

`Alt+F8` to clear screen and `Ctrl-L` to skip page

Using `sh bash` adding a command

If you use `console2` or same consoles,  you can add this `sh code` as without extension this location : ..\cygwin64\bin\

`cls` and /or `clear` (without extension)

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "\033c"
```

Then you can use `cls` and|or `clear` in cygwin command.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar and upon researching I found the above answers, I tried to follow some of the above solutions, I added the line to .bashrc, but it did not accept the function, I  tweaked around and found out another solution...it basically executes the ' printf "\33c" but instead of tweaking the .bash.rc file, you simply go to the directory - /cygwin/bin ,
Write the following command :- printf "\033c" 
And save it with the filename "cls" , in the bin directory, ensure that there is NO EXTENSION to the file, thus it will have the type "file" ..save it,open the shell and the command will run...

I found this method by playing around with msys and cygwin, I have both on my windows PC and turns out msys supports the "cls" command, I found a file with the same name in it's bin directory and copied it to the cygwin's bin folder and edited the file with the printf function and this worked like a charm...hope this helps.