# Clear console in cygwin console for windows: command not found

Tags: unix, console, posix

I use cygwin console for windows, but when I type clear, it says:

> command not found

How can I clear the console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the 'clear' command in Cygwin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249070/how-do-i-get-the-clear-command-in-cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

You may use Ctrl + L

On Linux the clear command would be cls, but this command doesn't seem to work in cygwin. (At least not when I tested it.)

Comment: Well then, why haven't you googled that? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249070/how-do-i-get-the-clear-command-in-cygwin