# Clear CMD-shell with php

Tags: php, windows, shell, cmd

I have this simple php script which outputs a string every second.

```
<?php
$i = 1;

while(1)
{
    exec("cls");    //<- Does not work
    echo "test_".$i."\n";

    sleep(1);
    $i++;
}
```

I execute the script in the command shell on windows (`php myscript.php`) and try to clear the command shell before every cycle. But I don't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no solutions at all, unless on Windows OS... you can start a bounty for that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php
$i = 1;
echo str_repeat("\n", 300); // Clears buffer history, only executes once
while(1)
{
    echo "test_".$i."\r"; // Now uses carriage return instead of new line

    sleep(1);
    $i++;
}
```

the `str_repeat()` function executes outside of the `while` loop, and instead of ending each echo with a new line, it moves the pointer back to the existing line, and writes over the top of it.

Comment: Thats a good workaround and i think it is the best possible solution yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

can you check this solution

```
$i = 1;
echo PHP_OS;

while(1)
{
    if(PHP_OS=="Linux")
    {
        system('clear');
    }
    else
        system('cls');
    echo "test_".$i."\n";

    sleep(1);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have to store the output of the variable and then `print` it to have it clear the screen successfully:

```
$clear = exec("cls");
print($clear);
```

All together:

```
<?php
$i = 1;

while(1)
{
    $clear = exec("cls");
    print($clear);
    echo "test_".$i."\n";

    sleep(1);
    $i++;
}
```

I tested it on Linux with `clear` instead of `cls` (the equivalent command) and it worked fine.

Comment: Oh, too bad. I tested on Linux and expected Windows to behave similarly by adapting the command (from `clear` to `cls`).

Answer (score 1):

**Duplicate of ➝ [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327544/how-can-clear-screen-in-php-cli-like-cls-command)**

Under Windows, no such thing as

```
@exec('cls');
```

Sorry! All you could possibly do is hunt for an executable (not the cmd built-in command) [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249071/444255)...

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the output to the terminal:

```
<?php
$i = 1;

while(1)
{
    exec("cls", $clearOutput);
    foreach($clearOutput as $cleanLine)
    {
         echo $cleanLine;
    }
    echo "test_".$i."\n";

    sleep(1);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is linux server use following command (`clear`)
if it is window server use `cls`
i hope it will work

```
$i = 1;

while(1)
{
    exec("clear");    //<- This will work
    echo "test_".$i."\n";

    sleep(1);
    $i++;
}
```

second solution

```
<?php
$i = 1;
echo PHP_OS;

while(1)
{
    if(PHP_OS=="Linux")
     {
        $clear = exec("clear");
        print($clear);
      }
    else
    exec("cls");
    echo "test_".$i."\n";

    sleep(1);
    $i++;
}
```

This one worked for me, tested also.

Comment: I tried your second solution on windows but it does not work. But thx!