# Why doesn't "exec" perform a command until I print its output?

Tags: php, linux, unix

I am onUbuntu 14.04, with PHP 5.5.9. There, I have a very simple file `a.php`:

```
<?php

$a = exec('clear');
print($a);
```

If I run the script as is now I get:

```
$ php a.php 
<screen cleared> # nothing is displayed in the screen
                 # "clear" was performed successfully
```

However, if I comment the `print($a)` to just have a file like this:

```
<?php

$a = exec('clear');
```

then nothing happens:

```
$ php a.php 
$               # nothing happened, I see the previous line above
```

To my understanding, it is the call to the variable `$a` what makes `clear` to be performed. But it doesn't make much sense, since [exec() docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) says:

> exec — Execute an external program

Is there a reason why `clear` doesn't get performed until `print()` is called?

Note this is related to the question [Clear CMD-shell with php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36568781/1983854) but I am asking here *why* this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, clear gets executed when calling exec. You just don't see its action on the screen until you actually output it.

Comment: But the action of `clear` is to clear the screen, why should I wait for its action to "happen" until a `print` happens?

Comment: clear simply outputs a couple of escape sequences. In your case, the output goes into $a. The terminal does not get cleared until you send that to it by printing it.

Comment: @fedorqui, in console do `clear | od -t x1`. As Adrian says, on *NIX systems, the console is controlled by the control codes. (See for example `man console_codes` on Linux). The computer where `clear` runs is not necessary the same where the console is. And it is not necessary a real console. The console codes form a protocol which allows application to control console regardless where it is or how it is implemented.

Comment: @Dummy00001 ok. So `clear` provides some control codes (33c, for example) that, together, clear the screen. Printing them effectively performs the action.

Comment: @fedorqui, precisely. `man terminfo` (or `man termcap` for older *nix systems; but also easier to read than terminfo man) for more information about where from the console codes come from. After than `man ncurses` for how to access the terminal capabilities database.